# OleDb connection string for a local file

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string, oledbconnection

Using OleDb I am connecting to MS Access (v2003) database and my Project folder is `MyHotApps` and my OleDb Connection String is

`MyConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Some User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MyHotApps\Database\MyDbFile.mdb'";`

As mentioned above my Project folder is `MyHotApps` and database file `MyDbFile.mdb` is located in `Project_Folder<MyHotApps>\Database\MyDbFile.mdb`

So, its too local for me that database file is inside the project folder and I need a **Portable Connection String** where ever I take the project folder I shouldn't rewrite Connection String for that I tried the below manner which didn't work

`MyConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source'=~Database\MyDbFile.mdb'";`

Can anybody help me how to build a **Portable Connection String** I read some forms that says Database file should be placed inside App_Data file and I don't know how to do that also. Anybody please tell me someway to build portable connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`HttpRequest.PhysicalApplicationPath`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx)

And do something as below might resolve your protable path issue easily...

```
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

Comment: Using `Request.ApplicationPath` responding me just `\MyHotApps` nothing more than that.

Comment: Unfortunately cannot use Request in Class file and getting error object is required while using HttpRequest.PhysicalApplicationPath.

Comment: Got it working with System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [**`OldDbConnectionStringBuilder`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)? Using that along with related  classes like `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` allow you to use simple constructors and properties to build up what you need. In addition the System.IO.Path class is handy for constructing directory paths. Typically when I need a default project directory (in a WPF app) I use
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. Then I use Path.Combine(base, filename) to create a full string to a file.

`System.IO.Directory` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` are also a useful.

Comment: Got it working with System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;